# Whirlpool Mysterious Ice Buildup

Tags: refrigerator, ice-maker, freezer

My whirlpool wrs325sdhz08 refrigerator has a mysterious ice buildup. From the pattern of the ice, it seems to be coming from a drip located somewhere near the ice maker at the top of the freezer.

The ice maker has been turned off for a few weeks as it was making a loud whining sound and the water dispenser on the freezer door has stopped dispensing water.

Here is the refrigerator manufacturer's label:
[image]

Here is the ice buildup which appears to be caused by the drip:
[image: ice buildup]

Ice maker with the ice bucket removed:
[image]

Comment: There should be a water shut off valve before the fridge.  Turn it off then can look for the leak.

Comment: IDK about your particular model, but some fridges have an issue where the defrost doesn't work, allowing ice buildup in the back of the cabinet.

Comment: As part of a recent fridge diagnosis I shut off the supply water for a few weeks to decide between leaky plumbing versus frost as the source of my ice. Turns out my plumbing was fine. If you live in the frozen North, then you might wait for freezing weather so you can comfortable defrost the freezer with its contents out in the cold. I wouldn't even shut off the water, but go about my business assuming that defrosting worked. There's a fan behind a false back of your freezer, where it might start whacking that ice and force you to defrost sooner. That fan may have already crapped out, though.